# Text to speech using embed

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, text-to-speech

I have this code and it works fine, but I have been struggling with how to get it to output a wav file that can be embedded in the page as opposed to making the user download and listen.
Any help is greatly appreciated. I'd like to be able to call the file directly with a query string so that it matches the captcha text. Model.InstanceData["Code"] is the captcha in a text string. I just can't seem to wrpa my head around it. Thanks!

```
private void _playBtn_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;

    if (context == null || context.Response == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    context.Response.Clear();

    context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "captcha.wav");
    context.Response.AddHeader("content-transfer-encoding", "binary");

    context.Response.ContentType = "audio/wav";

    SoundGenerator soundGenerator = new SoundGenerator(Model.InstanceData["Code"]);

    MemoryStream sound = new MemoryStream();

    // Write the sound to the response stream 
    soundGenerator.Sound.Save(sound, SoundFormatEnum.Wav);

    sound.WriteTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically after much playing around the solution was a little simpler than I thought. I created a new CaptchaPlayer.aspx player in my project and in the code behind used this:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PlayCaptchaSession();
    }

    private void PlayCaptchaSession()
    {
        object o = Session["captcha"];

        if (o != null)
        {
            HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;

            if (context == null || context.Response == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            //context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=" + "captcha.wav");
            context.Response.AddHeader("content-transfer-encoding", "binary");
            context.Response.ContentType = "audio/wav";
            SoundGenerator soundGenerator = new SoundGenerator(o as string);
            MemoryStream sound = new MemoryStream();
            // Write the sound to the response stream 
            soundGenerator.Sound.Save(sound, SoundFormatEnum.Wav);
            sound.WriteTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
        }
    }

}
```

After that I was able to add the embed to the form page

```
 <embed id='captchaAudio' width='1' height='1' enablejavascript='true' autostart='false' name='Verification code player' src='/CaptchaPlayer.aspx'>
                <noembed><a href='/CaptchaPlayer.aspx' title='Verification code wave audio file download'>Audio File</a></noembed>
                 <script type="text/javascript">
                 $(document).ready(function(){
                     $(".capLink").click(function () {
                         //alert(".click() called.");
                         document.getElementById('captchaAudio').Play();

                     });
                 });    
                </script>
```

And that did the trick! I hope this helps someone.